# When does Kud Wafter fit into the story?

Tags: little-busters

Kud Wafter is a spinoff of the original Little Busters! visual novel in which Kud is the main heroine. When, in the timeline, does it occur? Is it after Kud's route, or an alternative to Kud's route (i.e. after the common route) or in some other place in the story (e.g. after Refrain)? Of course, the name is a pun on "Wafu" (which Kud says frequently) and "After", but that alone doesn't seem to answer the question of how it fits into the main story.

[image]

Comment: You could say Kud Wafter as a possible continuation of all the events of Little Busters (Refrain).

Answer (score 1):

In the paradox world, Kyousuke chooses the "best candidates" not by their cutness (but they  are ^_^) but their life before die.

If you would realize, every non-core member from little busters had a bad life.
In this case, Kud had the feeling to say goodbye to her mother (she didn't it when she was alive).

This spinoff is after the events of Refrain (carcrash + good end = jumper).